# Alternative ways a vampire might 'turn' a human

Tags: fantasy-races, vampires

On the rare occasion a vampire has a reason to willingly cause a human he feeds on to rise as another vampire, what possible method might he have to do it?

I want to avoid the clichéd method of 'making the human swallow some of the vampire's blood before the human dies' (which isn't be possible for what I have in mind as vampires do not possess blood of their own).

Comment: What is the nature of the vampirism?  Viral, bacterial, magic?

Comment: @Draco18s: not bacterial or viral, the exact origins of the first vampires and how they learned to 'reproduce' (if it can be called that) are either lost to time or muddied up by mythology over the centuries (probably a little of both). They *are* walking dead and therefore don't draw breath, have beating hearts or give off body heat.

Answer (score 8):

**Teach it**

The stuff about drinking blood is all a myth. In reality vampires drain the very life from their victims - drinking their blood just happens to be the quickest way to do it.

The real secret is that vampirism is not a disease or infection of any kind, it is a supernatural teaching. Those who learn it became extremely attuned to their own life force up to the point when they sense how it slowly, inexorably escapes them. From then on it's only a short step towards various rituals that can transfer life from other sources... and the most efficient ways to do it are to tear it right out of other humans.

So when a vampire decides to adopt a student, the teaching might start with repeatedly draining the prospect so that they will appreciate their life force more. Note that the student doesn't have to be a volunteer at all and the whole thing can take a form of dark seduction - will they learn, or will they die miserably? For some this is a greater tragedy than being infected by a monster - it is the knowing turning of oneself into a monster.

Comment: This is a great idea

Answer (score 5):

**Inject the human with the agent**
When mosquitoes feed, they first inject an anticoagulant to keep the blood from thickening. This is what makes mosquito bites itch.

If the vampire had an extra gland in the mouth, like a snake perhaps, that it could use to inject whatever agent causes the change, then it could turn a human without having to kill them.

One bite, inject, and after the incubation period the person wakes up as a vampire.

Comment: Or the human *usually* wakes up as a vampire. At least on the Diskworld, if the vampire overreaches itself, Granny Weatherwax wins through and the vampire gets a bad dose of waking up as human. The same plot twist could work well in other fantasy worlds.

Comment: @nigel222 If only we all had the willpower of Granny Weatherwax

Answer (score 3):

A mystical binding of the soon/recently departed soul to its mortal shell.  Of course it will be part of the mystical rites that make the person a vampire instead of a ghost or ghoul...

The rite could be something fairly simple but needing to make preparations would make it harder to be an 'accident'.

Answer (score 3):

**Feed repeatedly:**

If you want to keep the nature of vampirism in your universe obscure (ie, not clearly magical or scientific), you could just require that a vampire feed from the same person multiple times while the person is still weakened from the previous feeding.

**Storytelling advantages:**

1. **Flexibility with timing**.  You could have the conversion take a dozen feedings over the course of a week, or three feedings over the course of a night.  You can even make it take longer for stronger or "hardier" humans.
2. **It keeps the nature of vampirism obscure**.  This feeding method could be caused by virus which requires a weak host in order to take hold, or it could be a mystical curse which requires that the human's *soul* be weakened.
3. **It could arise by chance.**  If any human might turn after repeated feedings, it's imaginable that the first vampire[s] might have captured and fed on ancient humans as cattle, and passed on their affliction by accident.
4. **It gives a lot of room for tension.** A character could have a longer period of time to worry about conversion, wait for rescue, or plot an escape.

Comment: IIRC, this is also the method in the original Dracula story, where one of the characters love interests is fed on and slowly turned over the course of months until she eventually dies and becomes a vampire.

Comment: @AndyD273 D'oh!  I never read the original, and I don't have time at the moment to look into it, but if my suggestion is an unintentional duplicate, I'll delete it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it honestly! Even if it is similar/the same, it's not a bad idea. I didn't mean it as a criticism, just an observation, and the rest of your points are valid. Leave it.

Comment: @AndyD273 ok...you win this round.

Comment: @AndyD273: Didn't Dracula also have to feed her some of his blood?

Comment: @sumelic You know, I don't remember exactly. For some reason I don't think they ever mention Dracula feeding Lucy his own blood to turn her, just feeding on her night after night until she dies of blood loss, but he does feed Mina his blood to turn and control her, which happens almost instantly, and she doesn't technically die from it. Mina is released from the curse when he dies and goes back to being a normal human. It's been a while since I read Dracula, so I could be missing some points.

Comment: @AndyD273: Oh yeah, I think I was confusing what happened to her with what happened to Mina. It seems the text never says that Lucy is fed any of his blood, according to the answers to this Sci-Fi SE question: [How does Dracula turn people into vampires?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38788/how-does-dracula-turn-people-into-vampires)

Comment: Liesmith: just because your answer duplicates what was done in fiction, that doesn't make your answer wrong. If anything, modern authors could benefit more from learning from the past instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. It was a great answer and you get a +1 because of it!

Answer (score 1):

**Animals**

Chinese and Slavic mythologies both thought vampires were created when [a cat or dog jumped over a corpse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire#Creating_vampires).It needs a little tweaking to not be overly easy to do, but there are plenty of ways to adjust. Pick and choose as many as necessary from the below.

- **Fresh Corpse**: It has to be a recently deceased body, maybe as little as a day or an hour.
- **Cause of Death**: Only someone killed by an existing vampire can be brought back this way.
- **Specific Animal**: Only a certain species of dog, or only black cats, will do. Maybe even only vampire cats or the Chupacabra can.
- **Timing**: Only at midnight, or under a full moon, or during an equinox.
- **Ritual**: After the animal jumps over the corpse, something else is necessary to complete it. Words, pentagrams, whatever.

Most legends have a kernel of truth, so anything involving an animal that could have been misunderstood to be a cat jumping over a corpse will do.

Answer (score 1):

**A Curse**

There are a number of alternate ways based on various myths.  Note that each region (and/or town) had their own mythical evil creature of the night.  Bram Stoker simply aggregated a number of these and called the result "vampyr."  The same sets of myths give us werewolves (Dracula can turn into a wolf).

Most myths don't use blood transfer as the method of transmission.  Most vampire types are created through curses.

So, methods of getting cursed:

1. A witch - often when there were unexplained deaths in a village
   (disease) they would disinter the most recent corpse, "destroy" it
   and the look for a scapegoat to kill as the witch responsible for
   it.
2. Maliciousness of the vampire's mortal self - They brought it on by
   there own actions: gluttony, murder, etc.
3. A vampire calls your name from the city walls - actually the myths just have the victim dying but there's no reason they couldn't turn.
4. Unrequited revenge - "I'll get you if I have to claw my way from
   Hell."

Answer (score 0):

### A Deal with the Devil

Vampires in pop culture(especially the new breed spearheaded by the Twilight series) are the results of a conspiracy by actual vampires; a kind of subliminal recruiting advertisement. The objective is to associate vampires with being "cool" or "romantic" or other positive qualities among the general public. This seeds the ground for the next step.

In the next phase, they make use of their chief weapon of coercion, the predatory contract. This can take many forms, examples being a [hidden clause somewhere that makes you sign away your soul](https://www.geek.com/games/gamestation-eula-collects-7500-souls-from-unsuspecting-customers-1194091/) or borrowing cash from an oddly pallid Mafioso. Regardless of the exact details, it sets the victim/"new recruit" up for a visit from an agent representing Nosferatu & Sons Capital, here to foreclose your body and soul. Resistance from the target is unlikely to be effective because of incredulity("this can't be real right?") and/or strong positive associations("you guys are actually vampires?! awesome!"). Exactly what pop culture vampires were set up to do.

Once the candidate has been locked in, the actual process of conversion is a combination of rigorous brainwashing, extreme ascetic practices([like seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6iAdM5K9Jo)), and body modification from specialists(the exact details are a blank for the OP to fill in). The candidate would be constantly encouraged along the way through Phil Jackson talks and MLM-esque tactics("Vampires are awesome right?! You wanna be a vampire right?! Then show your commitment by slicing out your kidneys!")

Answer (score 0):

I also strongly disagree with these simplist concepts that either biting or making someone drink vampire blood will turn you into a vampire.

The main problem I see with these approaches are the fact that vampires a quite powerful beings. So if you have a turning method that is this easy and with no drawbacks to the "master", vampire numbers in a given region should be alarming - which is a significant couterpoint, since they're, most of the times, depicted as outcasts that hide in the shadows for fear of being exterminated by  humans.

I would also like to state that I really like that old idea of a recently turned vampire spending a few centuries in service of a "master" who, ideally, acts as an afterlife guide, showing his new pupil the way into this gothic new world.

All that being said plus the fact that you're giving us the opportunity to choose it (and other options have been taken by previous answers), I'm gonna go with a concept I came up with a few years back, called...

### Heritage

Vampires grow stronger with age. As a rule, older means stronger.

To turn a human into a pupil, the vampire must sacrifice a significant amount of his power - which is lost, given to the newborn.

It will take decades, centuries even, for this vampire to regain this lost strength ('cause he will have to age these lost centuries invested in the creation of his "son") - which makes the act of turning someone an act of benevolence - the ultimate gift of power and immortality.

The counterpart for the turned is that he is physically obliged to obey his master. No matter what is asked, the pupil must abide or something bad happens (up to you to decide what. In my case, unimaginable debilitating pain).

This servitude, however, will come to an end. As time passes, the power the master has over his pupil continuously decreases. This happens because, as the master regains his strength, this "seal" that bonds master and pupil gets weaker, meaning the pupil starts to "have a voice". The physical pain will get proportionally weaker as time passes, until the master is "complete" again (meaning he has regained all the power lost in the turning process). At this point, the pupil is completely free.

Also worth noting that, if the master desires, he can set the pupil free at anytime, but only if he truly wishes to do so (can't be coerced to do it).

Answer (score -1):

You say you don't want to go with the *classic* method of the human feeding on the vampire's blood and say it's not even possible anyways... but why not?

The blood in the vampire's circulatory system doesn't have to be their own naturally generated blood. In fact, one has to consider: why would an undead immortal need to feed at all? The blood being drank has to fulfill some need, especially since the vampire wouldn't have a working stomach to digest the fluid. Obviously the blood in a vampire's veins is blood obtained from former meals and drinking human blood helps replace the expired "coolant."

Since this blood is able to convert humans to vampires, we need to understand how. The best answer would be a chemical agent in the blood or a viral agent that infects the host. Both possibilities could give way to alternative methods of infection.

First, the chemical agent. Vampires are eternally their age (in most depictions), highly resilient, and [know kung-fu](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/BuffyTheVampireSlayer). The easiest way to explain this is their bodies are somehow producing a chemical that allows them to have these features. (In the case of Kung-Fu, obviously their reaction speeds are being heightened and these instinctual movements *clearly* just *look* like Kung-Fu and aren't *really* the same art... or humans learned kung-fu from vampires. One of the two.) Since it's a chemical and not a biological agent (like a virus), any means of "feeding" this to a human should have the desired effect of turning them into a vampire. This can probably be done based on the themes you're aiming for. If your story is meant to be a romance, kissing/salivary transfer of the agent could result in a gradual process of transformation. If it's meant to be more... adult. You could have [*the less "family-friendly" kind of embrace*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnusualEuphemism) be a means of pretty much guaranteeing transformation so long as some of the fluid is ingested. If you want to go with something less romantic or sexual, you can use a serum formulated from a vampire's bodily fluids (sweat, saliva, blood, whatever) that can be injected to perform the transformation. Additionally, if magic is in this world, you can use a spell or a Deal With the Devil, but that doesn't really fit either of these categories. Just be sure if they do the latter, [they should be deterred from any *very enthusiastic* walks at any cost.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WebVideo/HellsingUltimateAbridged?from=WebVideo.HellsingAbridged)

If it's done through a viral agent, it could be that merely biting the human risks them getting infected. Viruses have an easier time infecting people who are weakened, and being near death is a classic way of weakening someone. It's a classic trope for the [dead](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/DragonBallZ) or [nearly dead](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/OnePiece) to [come back stronger](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CameBackStrong), after all. Having a reason to explain why makes it that much better. That said, depending on the human, it's possible they've developed a resistance or immunity to the virus that prevents infection. In that case, you may want to take the path of HIV/AIDS and make the virus a retrovirus that is hard to fight off. This could give other, interesting societal implications as well by bringing up the question of "are vampires really to blame" and "shouldn't we find a cure instead of killing them?" As for transmission, you can use any of the aforementioned transmission methods. It could even be that any contact with infected fluids can cause the transformation, so vampires prefer to kill their victims outright instead of trying to keep them alive since it means more predators feeding on prey for survival.